# Which anime episodes of Yu-Gi-Oh Duel Monsters and Yu-Gi-Oh GX correspond to which manga chapters?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I noticed that on the wiki it doesn't say which Manga Chapter each Yu-Gi-Oh DM and Yu-Gi-Oh GX episode is based on or which episode each Chapter is adapted to.

I don't have all Yu-Gi-Oh Manga Volumes and I only want to watch episodes based on which chapters I have. so which anime episodes of Yu-Gi-Oh and Yi-Gi-Oh GX correspond to which manga chapters and which episodes are original?

Comment: Wasn't this question asked before? I remarked that in the case of GX, there is virtually no overlap. Was the previous question deleted?

Comment: Yes. I don’t know why and the dm question wasn’t properly answered.

Comment: Hence why it was just a comment. Before re-posting the same question, if it was not you who deleted the original post, you should ask on the Meta why it was removed before posting it again.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: You just need to ask why on here: https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/